# Need help in parsing an alloy composition string into its elements and percentages

Tags: regex, parsing

I have created a rexexp function in Access 2010 and am attempting to write a query that parses a metal alloy composition string into individual elements and their respective percentages.
A couple examples of the alloy string are: 
***bi50 pb24.95 sn12.5 cd12.5 ag.05***
and
***sn96.5 ag3 cu.5***

So far, I have successfully used regular expressions to get the first element (EL1), the first percent (%1), and the second element (EL2).  But have not been able to get further.  The query I have written so far is:

```
SELECT tJobTime.Alloy, 
UCase(regexp([alloy],"[a-z]+",False)) AS EL1, 
regexp([alloy],"\d+\.?\d+",False) AS [%1], 
UCase(regexp([alloy],"\s[a-z]+",False)) AS EL2, 
regexp([alloy],"[a-z]+\s\d",False) AS [%2]
'Have not gone further because not sure of the correct regexp pattern
FROM tJobTime;
```

I am very new to regular expressions and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can't you parse it in some programming language? Regex doesn't seem to be the best tool for the job...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Deltharis, but my experience is mostly with Access and the data is in an Access db, thus trying to find a solution within that scope.

Comment: And how did you populate your DB with that data? What you're trying to do is a rather staightforward sequential task (split on spaces, split elements from percentages), but in this from, regex usage in an SQL statement... It's not an answer, I'm not sure of it, but it might be impossible.